# How to get started coding In-App Purchase

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working on in-app purchase. In my application we added the following code in appdelegate:

```
    #import "InappPurchaseAppDelegate.h"
    #import "MainController.h"
    #import "MKStoreManager.h"
    #import "MKStoreObserver.h"

    @implementation InappPurchaseAppDelegate

    @synthesize window;


    - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application 
    { 
      [MKStoreManager sharedManager];


      navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
      [window addSubview:navigationController.view];
      MainController *frontController =[[MainController alloc] init];
      [navigationController pushViewController:frontController animated:NO ];
      [frontController release];    // Override point for customization after      application launch
      [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
```

and added the following code in our controller:

```
    #import "MainController.h"
    #import "MKStoreManager.h"
    #import "MKStoreObserver.h"

    #import "InappPurchaseAppDelegate.h"


    @implementation MainController


    -(IBAction)InappPurchase:(id)sender
    {
      [[MKStoreManager sharedManager] buyFeatureA];

    }
```

I also added storekit framework but when the button is clicked nothing happens.

Comment: What is `MKStoreManager`? This is not a standard part of the iPhone SDK. Also, what do you mean "this did not work." _How_ did it not work? Run-time error messages? Refused to compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to know is here: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Overview%20of%20the%20Store%20Kit%20API/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH100-SW1

It shouldn't take you more than half a day to implement it (maybe a bit more if the content resides on your servers and is not already in the bundle).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest explaination is that your button is not properly configured to send the action message. To test either set a breakpoint for the method or log it like:

```
-(IBAction)InappPurchase:(id)sender
  {
     NSLog(@"Buyid method called");
     [[MKStoreManager sharedManager] buyFeatureA]; 
  }
```

If the NSLog or breakpoint are never hit, you need to check the button in Interface Builder and make such it's action is set to the InappPurchase method.

If the InappPurchase method is being called by the button then the problem is in the `MKStoreManger` object.

Comment: I am check this InappPurchase method is being called by the button. what is change in MkStoreManager object